# Breaking line in Bootstrap between 2 elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following login-like page code.

How can I break line between the two rows? Right now they directly next to each other, and I want the user and password input below the logo. I am using Bootstrap framework for this.

```
 .container
    .jumbotron.d-flex.align-items-center
      .row
        .col-sm-12
          img(src='assets/logo.png' width='418' height='120' style='display: block; margin: 0 auto;')
      .row
        .col-sm-12
          h3(style='display:block; margin: 0 auto;') Username
          input(type='text' placeholder='name')
        .col-sm-12
          h3(style='display:block; margin: 0 auto;') Password
          input(type='password' placeholder='password')
        .col-sm-12
          button#logIn.btn-primary.btn Log in
          p Forgot password?
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<br />` between the two rows?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work

Comment: How about `mb-4` to your `row` as I believe you're using Bootstrap v4.  The only other consideration I would offer is that based on the code above I don't see why you're applying `flex` to your Jumbotron component.  Grid is already flex and there doesn't seem to be a need for those classes.